# How to share session in local IIS across ports?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, visual-studio-2015

I have a web site on port 62587 and a web service (WCF) on port 15290, both localhost.

The login page is on 62587 and the WCF service is on 15290. How do I get it so that WCF can see the login credentials of 62587?

EDIT:
I have a  provider node with applicationName="MyApplication" set in both Web.config's.
I have:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms
         loginUrl="Signin/Welcome.aspx"
         name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
         protection="All"
         timeout="10"
         path="/"
         requireSSL="false"
         slidingExpiration="true"
         defaultUrl="default.aspx"
         cookieless="UseCookies"
         enableCrossAppRedirects="false"
         />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Im not sure if its possible to share the session without using web farm. However, have you tried to pass the login credentials to the WCF service, once the object containing login credentials arrives at WCF, it can be saved into its session or cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for forms authentication by setting the machine and decryption keys to be the same across all applications:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx

But this does not mean your session state will be shared because this is per process.

To share session state you need to store session a shared database such as [redis](https://github.com/Azure/aspnet-redis-providers) or [sql server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx).

Comment: Thanks - your clue led me to this article by Peter Bromberg which I think explains my challenge quite well. I plan to test it soon, but I'm upvoting based on it leading me to more clues. http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2006/10/cross-application-forms-authentication.html